# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number' while encoding

Tags: javascript, angular

Here is the function .It is giving this error:-
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'

```js
function b64EncodeUnicode(str) {    
  return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g,
    function toSolidBytes(match, p1) {
        return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
    }));
}
```

Comment: you code snippet seems working fine on my local

Comment: @PardeepJain Are you trying this code in angular 6?
Because in javascript there is no type checking

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass number but you are passing `0px`, so just use this code -

```
b64EncodeUnicode(str) {    
    return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g,
      function toSolidBytes(match, p1) {
          return String.fromCharCode(0 + p1);
      }));
  }
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6e2j2n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: function is working fine for text only . But how to decode smileys . If i have a combination of both text and smiley like this :-
hi all (thumbs up)

Comment: I am not sure about this

Answer (score 0):

try to cast string to number before using it, like this:

```
return String.fromCharCode(Number('0x' + p1));
```